# How to convert a number of a webservice by a character string of another webservice?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a web service that displays => `Year`, `Country` and `National register`.

[image]

Here is the code

service.ts

```
getDta(obj: SearchDta): Observable < SearchDtaResponse > {
    return this.http.post < SearchDtaResponse > (this.api + `/DTA`, {
            REGISTRENAT: obj.registreNational,
            EXERCICE: obj.fiscalYear,
            PAYS: obj.country,
            MODE: 'D',
        },

    );
}
```

component.ts

```
  registreNational: string | null = null;
  country: string | null = null;
  fiscalYear: string | null = null;
  countries: Country[] = []; 


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registreNational = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('registreNational');
    this.country = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('country');
    this.fiscalYear = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('fiscalYear');

    if (!this.registreNational || !this.country || !this.fiscalYear) {
        this.goBack();
        return;
    }

    this.getDta();
  }

  private getDta(): void {
    let searchDta = new SearchDta(parseInt(this.registreNational + ''), parseInt(this.fiscalYear + ''), parseInt(this.country + ''));
    this.service.getDta(searchDta).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            this.dta = res.DTA;

        }
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<tr>
   <th>Year</th>
   <td>{{ fiscalYear }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Country</th>
   <td>{{ country }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>National register</th>
   <td>{{ registreNational }}</td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that I want to replace the `4` value with the name of a country. I have to use another WebService to convert.

Normally the code below is correct...

service.ts

...

```
getPaysDta(): Observable < Country[] > {
    return this.http.post < SpecificParametersResponse > (this.api + `/TXT`, {
        CODE: "PAYS_DTA",
        ID: 1,
        LISTEBOOL: "TRUE"
    }).pipe(
        map(res => {
            if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
                return res.TEXTE.LISTE.map(item => {
                    console.log("Countries => " + JSON.stringify(res.TEXTE.LISTE));
                    return {
                        id: item.CODE,
                        name: item.COURT
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        })
    );
}
```

country.ts

```
export class Country {
    id : string;
    name: string;
}
```

I did a console.log, I retrieve the countries

[image]

component.ts

In the `ngOnInit():` method, I added this:

```
this.service.getPaysDta().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe((countries) => this.countries = countries);
```

...

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registreNational = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('registreNational');
    this.country = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('country');
    this.fiscalYear = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('fiscalYear');

    if (!this.registreNational || !this.country || !this.fiscalYear) {
        this.goBack();
        return;
    }

    this.getDta();

    this.service.getPaysDta().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe((countries) => this.countries = countries);
  }
```

I don't understand how to I have to modify the HTML file, now ?

```
<tr>
   <th>Country</th>
   <td>{{ country }}</td>
</tr>
```

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `this.country = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('country');` evaluates as `4`...

I would make the following change:

```
// new prop
selectedCountry: Country;

// update this
this.service.getPaysDta().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe((countries) => {
    this.countries = countries;

    // get your selected country
    let selectedCountry = this.countries.find(c => c.id == this.country);
    if(selectedCountry){
        this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    }
});
```

And then in your template:

```
<tr>
   <th>Country</th>
   <td>{{ selectedCountry.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Zze: Thank you for your help. I have another error message now on the line => `this.selectedCountry = this.countries.find(c => c.id == this.country);` the message is the following => `Type 'Country | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Country'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Country'`, I edited my first message with a screenshort.

Comment: @devostOliv Please see updated code. It was complaining because `.find()` may return no result.

Comment: In the HTML page, it is displayed  `[object Object]`, I edited my first message. If you have another solution, I'm interested

Comment: @devostOliv Apologies... should be this: `<td>{{ selectedCountry.name }}</td>` I have updated the answer as well.